# PowerShell Search software installed

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to get this ForEach loop to search for specific software install on a computer using a registry search. For some reason it is only find one and not the other two even though I know and can see they are installed.
What have a missed.

```
Clear-Host
$Computers = hostname

$array = @()

foreach($pc in $computers){

    $computername=$pc.computername

    #Define the variable to hold the location of Currently Installed Programs

    $UninstallKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 

    #Create an instance of the Registry Object and open the HKLM base key

    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername) 

    #Drill down into the Uninstall key using the OpenSubKey Method

    $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 

    #Retrieve an array of string that contain all the subkey names

    $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 

    #Open each Subkey and use GetValue Method to return the required values for each


    ForEach($Key in $subkeys) {
        $thisKey=$UninstallKey+"\\"+$key 

        $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 
        #If found set variable to True for used in report

            if (($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "CCleaner")) {Write-Host "CCleaner = True"}
            Else {Write-Host = " False"}

        if (($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "*7-Zip*")) {Write-Host "7Zip = True"}
            Else {Write-Host = " False"}

        if (($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "*.NET Framework*")) {Write-Host ".NET  = True"}
            Else {Write-Host = " False"}


    } 

}
```

It finds DotNet and its equals True, but the 7-Zip and CCleaner are also installed and in the place I am looking. I have a looked at this code for a while now and can not see why.

I know I have set the computers to hostname, I will change to a file with a list of computers. This is just for test at the moment.

Thank you and in advance.

Comment: 64-bit OS? Chances are you have a 32-bit application and they are located in the WoW6432Node. Your CCLeaner `-like` statement has no wildcards. I would suggest using `-match` instead of `-like`, and remove the asterisks. That may well solve your problem. Since 7-Zip's displayname starts with 7-Zip I don't remember if `-like` will find it if you put an asterisks in front of the text. match is better than like in my opinion when it can be used.

Comment: It is 64-Bit OS, i might have to cater for both in that case  I have added the wildcards to the names and removed the else statement. So far it working I think, i will keep test for fake software to see if reports back as it should. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all of your `If` statements could be replaced with a `Switch` statement that would work faster and better (one call to get the value from the remote registry instead of 3), plus it can regex match. Consider removing all 3 of your `If` statements and replacing them with:

```psh
Switch -Regex ($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName")){
    "CCleaner" {Write-Host "CCleaner = True";continue}
    "7-Zip" {Write-Host "7-Zip = True";continue}
    "\.Net Framework" {Write-Host ".Net Framework = True"}
}
```

That should effectively do the same thing as all of your `If` statements

**Edit:** How to get the 32 bit keys... Well, you already have the code to get things from the registry, just tack on a second part after the switch basically with a modified path. Better yet, let's make a single list of all the applications installed from the DisplayName values, add all the ones from the Wow6432Node section to that list, and then run the whole list through the `Switch`. Now I assume that, since you are referencing a `computername` property in your code, you are importing a CSV and looping through that? I hope so, I kind of based this off that. So this will loop through computers in a CSV where the computer name is stored in a `computername` property. It will add 3 new properties to each computer: `CClean`, `7-Zip`, and `.Net Framework`. It sets them all as `$false` by default. Then it pulls the software listings, and if it finds any of those it changes that property to `$true`.

```psh
Clear-Host
$Computers = @($(new-object PSObject -prop @{'ComputerName' = $env:COMPUTERNAME}))
##Computers = Import-CSV 'C:\Path\To\SCCMVerify.csv'

$array = @()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $computers.count;$i++){

    $computername=$computers[$i].computername
    Add-Member -InputObject $computers[$i] -NotePropertyName 'CCleaner' -NotePropertyValue $false
    Add-Member -InputObject $computers[$i] -NotePropertyName '7-Zip' -NotePropertyValue $false
    Add-Member -InputObject $computers[$i] -NotePropertyName '.Net Framework' -NotePropertyValue $false



    #Define the variable to hold the location of Currently Installed Programs

    $UninstallKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 
    $Uninstall32Key="SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 

    #Create an instance of the Registry Object and open the HKLM base key

    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername) 

    #Drill down into the Uninstall key using the OpenSubKey Method

    $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 
    $reg32key=$reg.OpenSubKey($Uninstall32Key) 

    #Retrieve an array of string that contain all the subkey names

    $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 
    $sub32keys=$reg32key.GetSubKeyNames() 

    #Open each Subkey and use GetValue Method to return the required values for each, compile that in a list

    $applications = $subkeys|ForEach{$reg.OpenSubKey("$UninstallKey\\$_").GetValue('DisplayName')}
    $applications += $sub32keys|ForEach{$reg.OpenSubKey("$Uninstall32Key\\$_").GetValue('DisplayName')}

    #Search all applications for matching software
    Switch -Regex ($applications) {
        "CCleaner" {Write-Host "CCleaner = True";$Computers[$i].CCleaner = $true ;continue}
        "7-Zip" {Write-Host "7-Zip = True";$computers[$i].'7-Zip' = $true;continue}
        "\.Net Framework" {Write-Host ".Net Framework = True";$Computers[$i].'.Net Framework' = $true}        
    } 

}
```

Comment: Sweet, looks good. I will give it a try and more software to it. This is basically for a Task Sequence in SCCM at end of the build to let me know if all software has been installed.

Comment: Also just thought, could I get it to check the Wow6432Node

Comment: Ok, I reposted a whole script, modified to check both keys. I made some other modifications that you can take or leave.