# How to scan and uninstall the software?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to uninstall the QuickTime application in my network after the Apple news. 
However, I don't want to remove this application from Mac computers.

In addition, I'm not sure how to scan and uninstall this application from my network.

Is there any PowerShell script to scan on how many computers QuickTime is installed? How can I remove this application?

I tried this:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match "Quick time "
}

$app.Uninstall()
```

Comment: This is two questions. 1) How to scan to find out if software is installed, and 2) how to uninstall that software. So break it into two tasks. Start with the first one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/29813325/62576 should get you started). When you've done that, find a solution for the second half, and then you can combine them.

Comment: *"I tried this"* ... and the result was?